# Adding ints* to a pointer array

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm having a lot of trouble working with the nuances of pointers. I'm trying to add references to integers to an array of int pointers but I can't seem to quite get it right. This is my code:

```
int main()
{
    ATree<int> testTree;
    int nums[12] = {5,4,3,7,6,1,2,12,15,9,8,11};
    int *ptr;
    int num, a;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        a = nums[i];
        *ptr = a;
        testTree.add(nums[i]);
    }
    cout << "Enter a value to search for" << endl;
    cin >> num;
    cout << testTree.search(num) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

ATree.h

```
template <typename Item>
class ATree
{
    public:
    ATree();
    void add(Item);
    void add_helper(int, Item);
    int search(Item);
    int search_helper(int, Item);
    int get_size();
    private:
    int size;
    Item* tree[40];
};
#include "ATree.hpp"
```

ATree.hpp

```
template <typename Item>
ATree<Item>::ATree()
{
for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i)
{ tree[i] = nullptr }
size = 0;
}
template <typename Item>
void ATree<Item>::add(Item obj)
{
    int n = 1;
    if ((tree[1]) == nullptr)
    {
        tree[1] = &obj;
    }
    else
    {
         add_helper(n, obj);
    }
}
template <typename Item>
void ATree<Item>::add_helper(int n, Item obj)
{       
    if (tree[n] == nullptr)
    {
        tree[n] = &obj;
    }
    else if (&obj > tree[n])
    {
        n = 2*n+1;
        add_helper(n, obj);
    }
    else
    {
        n = 2*n;
        add_helper(n, obj);
        }
    }
template <typename Item>
int ATree<Item>::search(Item obj)
{
    int n = 1;
    if (&obj == tree[1])
        { return 1; }
    else
        { return search_helper(n, obj);}
    }
template <typename Item>
int ATree<Item>::search_helper(int n, Item obj)
    {
    if (&obj == tree[n])
        { return n; }
    else if (&obj > tree[n])
    {
        n = 2*n+1;
        return search_helper(n, obj);
    }
    else
    {
        n = 2*n;
        return search_helper(n, obj);
    }
}
template <typename Item>
int ATree<Item>::get_size()
{return size;}
```

Conceptually I find pointers relatively simple but once they start being passed between classes or arrays (it seems arrays handle them differently?) it starts getting very counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: `tree[1] = &obj;` that's not working. You need to store the element in your tree, after all you have 40 places for them, change the type to store the object itself. This is a temporary object, taking its address and storing it not working.

Comment: Same with `if (&obj == tree[1])`. Never going to be true.

Comment: actually one of my errors is that, apparently, it's true every time

Comment: _references to integers_  sounds fishy to me

Comment: In main, you do `*ptr = a;` which assigns whatever ptr is pointing to, but ptr is never assigned to point to anything. At this moment, ptr and a aren't actually used, so they could be removed, avoiding comments like this one.

Comment: You're right I'm not passing references to ints, I'm passing pointers (I hope)

Comment: passing pointers to temporary objects. Bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically store objects, not pointers:

```
Item tree[40];
```

And then in your comparison, compare the objects, not their pointers:

```
template <typename Item>
void ATree<Item>::add(Item obj)
{
    int n = 1;
    if ((tree[1]) == nullptr) // USe a counter here instead, to know how many objects are stored
    {
        tree[1] = obj;
    }
    else
    {
         add_helper(n, obj);
    }
}
template <typename Item>
void ATree<Item>::add_helper(int n, Item obj)
{       
    if (tree[n] == nullptr)
    {
        tree[n] = obj;
    }
    else if (obj > tree[n])
    {
        n = 2*n+1;
        add_helper(n, obj);
    }
    else
    {
        n = 2*n;
        add_helper(n, obj);
        }
    }
template <typename Item>
int ATree<Item>::search(Item obj)
{
    int n = 1;
    if (obj == tree[1])
        { return 1; }
    else
        { return search_helper(n, obj);}
    }
}
template <typename Item>
int ATree<Item>::search_helper(int n, Item obj)
    {
    if (obj == tree[n])
        { return n; }
    else if (&obj > tree[n])
    {
        n = 2*n+1;
        return search_helper(n, obj);
    }
    else
    {
        n = 2*n;
        return search_helper(n, obj);
    }
}
```

This code is not tested and doesn't work as is, as you have to add a counter to check how many elements you actually storing (I would advise to use a `std::vector<>`) and there is no boundary check either.

Comment: thanks. but is there any way to use pointers in my base array? I would have thought that, with an array of pointers, the pointers will still point to the correct thing.

Comment: No, you can't store pointers to temporary objects. Or pass them as const& and then do your pointer storing. But if one of the int goes out of scope...